# how to get the second (third...) occurence of a substring in xslt?

Tags: string, xslt, substring

I have a long String separated with the equal sign(=)as delimiter,something like this:

```
AAA=BBBBB=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC=D=FFFFF=GG=H
```

The substrings can have arbitrary length.If I want to get the first substring I can use the substring-before function like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($vari, '=')"/>
```

But is there a way to get only the second, (third, etc) substring?
I need **BBBBB** instead of AAA=BBBBB and **CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC** instead of  AAA=BBBBB=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC so substring-before-last won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xslt-1.0: 
This could be done by a combination of  substring-after and substring-before.
Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                substring-after ($vari, , '=')
               , '=')"/>
```

For BBBBB
Or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                 substring-after ( substring-after ($vari,  '='),  '=')
                 , '=')"/>
```

For CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.

Attention: Not tested.

With xslt-2.0 there may be better ways.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Ugly as hell, but it is probably the fault of xslt.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you have [EXSLT's String extension elements](http://www.exslt.org/str/index.html) available, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize($vari, '=')[2]" />
```

Using your above string, this would return `BBBBB`.

In XPath 2.0, this function is built in:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize($vari, '=')[2]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an xslt-1.0 solution that doesn't require the use of extensions and works with arbitrary separator lengths an separator occurrences:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="substring-nth-occurrence-position">
      <xsl:with-param name="string">aaa_#bbb_#ccc_#dddd_#ee</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="substr">_#</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="occurrence">3</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>      
  </xsl:template>      

  <xsl:template name="substring-nth-occurrence-position">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="substr"/>
    <xsl:param name="occurrence"/>
    <xsl:param name="current_iteration" select="1"/> 
    <xsl:param name="accumulated_length" select="0"/> 

    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- in case occurrence is greater than the number of instances of substr return 0 -->
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($string, $substr))">0</xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- determine the position of the next instance of substr in the (remaining part of ) string and add it to accumulated_length-->
        <xsl:variable name="v.accumulated_length_new">
          <xsl:variable name="v.idx.of.substr">
            <xsl:call-template name="instr">
              <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="$substr"/>     
            </xsl:call-template>              
          </xsl:variable>    

          <xsl:value-of select="$accumulated_length + $v.idx.of.substr"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable> 

        <!-- if current_iteration equals occurrence then return accumulated length... -->
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$current_iteration= $occurrence ">
            <xsl:value-of select="$v.accumulated_length_new" />
          </xsl:when>  

          <!-- ... else run another iteration-->            
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-nth-occurrence-position">
              <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $substr)"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="$substr"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="occurrence" select="$occurrence"/>                 
              <xsl:with-param name="current_iteration" select="$current_iteration + 1"/> 
              <xsl:with-param name="accumulated_length" select="$v.accumulated_length_new + string-length($substr) - 1"/>                 
            </xsl:call-template>    
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>  
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>    


  <!-- returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string -->
  <xsl:template name="instr">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="substr"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="contains($string,$substr)*(1 + string-length(substring-before($string,$substr)))"  />
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Execution result of the above example is 14).